# How to play animation in listview like Google Play Music?

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to give a similar animation in a `listview`, but am stuck at the starting. What approach should I take, GIF, Sprite animation or is there something else?

Any useful tutorials?

In the image the item in the `listview` animates when the music plays.

Comment: Use AnimationDrawable: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html